# Programmatically create a controller

Tags: android

I would like to know how I can create a controller which is programmatically created. What I want to do is to create an app running in background which act as if a real controller was connected to the device. But I can't find resources on that subject. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: What kind of controller? Like a keyboard or gamepad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, as chkri does, that by "controller", you mean some sort of input device, what you want is not possible, except on a rooted device or probably in a ROM mod. Production apps cannot inject input into other apps.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any articles/resources to do this with a rooted rom?

Comment: @E-Kami: Not handy. My understanding is that this is typical done at the Linux level, so as to ensure that everything in Android proper gets the events through normal channels, but that's just based on my recollection of what I've seen mentioned elsewhere.